# bind a function to image source that embedded in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have a repeater that it has image inside itself. I want to show different image base on ranking for example if ranking is 1 I show an image and if it is 2 I show the other etc.and i have 5 kind of image and 5 grade too.

Ranking is a column in dataset. But my function does not work correctly and I can't get correct result. It only shows first pic. What solution do you suggest for this operation??

thank a lot .

This is my code

```
public string getimg()
{ 
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=.;database=site;integrated security=true;");
     string sSQL = "Select username ,weight,point , Rank() over(order by point desc) as 'ranking' from karbar order by point desc";  
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, con);
     SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     adapt.Fill(ds);
     foreach (DataRow myRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
     {
         if (Convert.ToInt32(myRow["ranking"]) == 1)

         { return "price/con1.png"; }
         else return "price/con2.png";
     }

     }
```

and its html

```
  <div class="innerTitle">
                <img style="width:55px;height:55px" alt=""  src="<%# getimg() %>" />     </div>
                  <div class="innerContent" style=" width: 391px; direction:rtl ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can try with this answer

1 Modify your function

```
public string getimg(int indexRow)
{ 
}
```

2 Add this selection code

```
  if (Convert.ToInt32(myRow["ranking"]) == 1 
         && Convert.ToInt32(myRow["yourIndex"]) == indexRow ) //in order to select nice row
  {  
     return "price/con1.png"; 
  }

  return "price/con2.png";
```

3 in your call you must have your index Row printed in your page, in order to select

```
img style="width:55px;height:55px" alt=""  src="<%# getimg(1) %>" />  //getimg(1) print first row.
```

4 Get you index

```
input type="hidden" runat="server" id="test" value="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "YourIndex") />%>" />
```

Comment: but i have 1 repeater and how pass parameter and how determine rank in repeater?

Comment: my real problem is get index. how can i do it?

Comment: thanks.Suppose i get a index and  i put it in getimage func it only compare this number but i wanna all of record Be reviewed.and each get own pic in repeater.suppose index is 2 all of record compare with 2 but i wanna in time call all of pic be allocated

Comment: so sorry that i get your time but where do i put '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "YourIndex") />%>'

Comment: That's normal quantum good luck my friend and if you need help i'am here

Answer (score 0):

try this:

**instead of Rank(), try row_number() function**

```
Select username ,weight,point , 
 ROW_NUMBER() over(order by point desc) as 'ranking'
 from karbar order by point desc
```

. Because If two user have the same rank, both of them would get rank as 1, whereas if you use row_number(), they would get 1 and 2 ranking